# Azure Function not accessing App Settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to convert a .NET application I currently have running as a Webjob to an Azure Function.

The application accesses an Azure SQL Database and obtains the connection string from the App Settings in the portal.  Currently this is the App Settings in the website's App Service (as it's a Webjob).

So I've created an Azure Function App, created a Powershell Timed Trigger and within the Run.ps1 I have:

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)";
cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe
Write-Output "PowerShell completed at:$(get-date)";
```

And I've added the connection strings to the App Settings of the Function App, but when I run the Function, I get the error: Could not find named connection string myconnectionstring

If I add the connection string directly into the MyApplication.exe.config, then it works perfectly.  It also works perfectly as a Webjob.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Just in-case this helps anyone else in future, here's the Powershell based on David's answer below:

```
$ConnStr = $env:SQLAZURECONNSTR_Nhibernate
$ConfigName = "MyApp.exe.config"
$Xml = [xml](gc $ConfigName)
$Node = $Xml.configuration.connectionStrings.ChildNodes | where {$_.name -eq "nhibernate" }
If($Node.connectionString -ne $ConnStr) {
    Write-Output "Updating Connection String";
    $Node.connectionString = $ConnStr
    $Xml.Save("D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyFunction\$ConfigName")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, that won't work if you just launch the exe. The way it works in WebJobs is that it makes a copy of your exe and transforms the .exe.config to have the appsetting.

One suggested workaround is to have your application rely on the `myconnectionstring` **environment variable** instead of app setting. That will work as all processes automatically inherit all those env variables.

An alternative workaround would be to deploy `MyApplication.exe.config` with a dummy value for the app setting, and then have the PowerShell script do a string replace using the value of the env variable before launching the process. And make sure it only resaves the file if the transform is not already done, as the act of saving will I thin restart the function.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Unfortunately I don't have any control over the code that gets the app setting.  It's NHibernate's Configuration, which gets it from the <property name="connection.connection_string_name">nhibernate</property> and then looks for the nhibernate connection string.

Is there another workaround you can suggest?

Comment: I just added a possible alternative.

Comment: Great idea!  Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to obtain the app settings from the portal using environment variables in Powershell! :S

Comment: Should be the standard $env:FOO

Comment: So if it's stored in the ConnectionStrings of the App Settings on the portal as NHibernate, then it would just be $env:NHibernate?  Because I'm trying Write-Output $env:NHibernate in my Run.ps1 and getting nothing.

Comment: It's okay, I figured it out: $env:SQLAZURECONNSTR_NHibernate